# launchctl error "nothing found to load" when run via cron

Tags: macos, terminal, launchd

On OS X 10.9, I'm running a script (e.g., `~/bin/run.sh`) via my user crontab (added using `crontab -e`). This script, under some specific conditions (not related to this question), will run the following command to launch a menubar application:

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/com.opendns.osx.RoamingClientMenubar.plist
```

When I run this command (either `~/bin/run.sh` or the `launchctl` statement above directly) from the command line normally, the menubar item launches fine.

When this command is run via crontab (again, directly or via `~/bin/run.sh`), I receive the message `nothing found to load` in the cron output (in my mail).

Question: why does this fail when run via cron but not when run on the command line?

I have tried executing it via cron in the simplest way possible:

```
* * * * * launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/com.opendns.osx.RoamingClientMenubar.plist
```

This doesn't work (I get `nothing found to load`).

I have tried emulating the cron environment:

1. Capturing the cron environment by having this execute in cron:

   ```
   env > ~/cronenv
   ```
2. Then opening a shell with this environment:

   ```
   env - `cat ~/cronenv` /bin/sh
   ```
3. And finally running the command:

   ```
   launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/com.opendns.osx.RoamingClientMenubar.plist
   ```

It runs find in these conditions (I wouldn't expect it to, if something in the cron environment is the culprit).

I have tried running it from crontab as `sudo`. Nope (`nothing found to load`).

I have tried running it from crontab with `launchctl load -F` and `launchctl load -w`. No luck (`nothing found to load`).

Permissions on the plist file are:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  561 Apr 13 20:55 /Library/LaunchAgents/com.opendns.osx.RoamingClientMenubar.plist
```

What's going on?

(BTW, I know it may seem silly to run a script with a launchctl job from within cron, but because it is run within a shell script it's prevented from being a 100% launchctl-controlled process.)

**Update:** as requested [here is the script](https://gist.github.com/quinncomendant/3be731567e529415d5ee#file-umbrella-L29) that is being run (I've been calling it `~/bin/run.sh`), the line in question being #29, and [here is the contents of the plist](http://hastebin.com/faxorejula).

**Update: the specific solution that works for me, based on @mateusz-szlosek's suggestion to use `bsexec`, looks like this:**

```
sudo launchctl bsexec "$(ps -axwww | grep Dock | grep -v grep | awk {'print $1'};)" sudo -u $USER launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/com.opendns.osx.RoamingClientMenubar.plist
```

The first `sudo` is required otherwise the error *Couldn't switch to new bootstrap port* occurs. The second `sudo` is to execute `launchctl` as `$USER`. The first argument to `bsexec` is a parent process ID who's context will be used to launch the new process. `$(ps -axwww | grep Dock | grep -v grep | awk {'print $1'};)` returns the `pid` of the Dock process, which loads somewhat early in the launchd hierarchy, but under user context.

Comment: How about `bsexec` to launch Agent in proper context? Have You checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106638/starting-stopping-a-launchd-agent-for-all-users-with-gui-sessions ?

Comment: `cron` has a option `load : be verbose when loading crontab files`. So it's confusing `launchctl`'s `load` options with it's own.

Try using $() or ` around the command.

Comment: @user14492 I don't think that's it because, despite my example above attempting to execute launchctl directly via cron, it actually is cron calling a bash script (`~/bin/run.sh`) which contains the launchctl commands.

Comment: Modify your question with the content of run.sh and the plist you want launchd to load.

Comment: isn't launchctl started by root, and cron by the user?

Comment: Updated with link to script and plist.

Comment: How does one supply `sudo` a password if the script is not interactive? Another suggestion is to avoid using tilde `~` expansion in your crontab because the `HOME` variable can be overridden. Use `/Users/$LOGNAME` or you can use `/Users/$USER` for a crontab. `USER` is exclusive for BSD systems.

Comment: Running `sudo` non-interavtively with `ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` in `/etc/sudoers`. And `~` works fine, that's not the problem.

Comment: @mateusz-szlosek, your suggestion to use `bsexec` seems to be working. If you'd be willing to write this up with details as an answer I can award the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is execution context and mach bootstrap in OS X (more info on [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794-CH1-SECTION9) worth reading). You need to simulate execution from proper context. In OS X it's done using `launchctl bsexec` command. From [TheDarkKnight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2068642/thedarkknight)'s answer to [Starting/stopping a launchd agent for all users with GUI sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31534614/3488699) you have:

> ### Unload Agents
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> for id in `ps aux | grep -v grep | grep MyAgent | awk {'print $2'}`
> do
>     launchctl bsexec $id launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/myAgent.plist
> done
> ```
>
> Replace `MyAgent` with the name of your Launch Agent.
>
> ### Load Agents
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> for pid_uid in $(ps -axo pid,uid,args | grep -i "[l]oginwindow.app" | awk '{print $1 "," $2}'); do
>
>     pid=$(echo $pid_uid | cut -d, -f1)
>     uid=$(echo $pid_uid | cut -d, -f2)
>
>     launchctl bsexec "$pid" chroot -u "$uid" / launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/myAgent.plist
> done
> ```

## On OS X 10.11 and Later

From the comment by [vrrathod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/191914/vrrathod) about OS X 10.11, El Capitain, use:

```
launchctl bootstrap gui/$uid /Library/LaunchAgents/myAgent.plist
```